# what is the best way to ensure images are not cahsed in client browsers when a new image is released?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, image, iis

We many times get the issue from customers that the new images released with the latest release to production website is not appearing in their browsers. What is the best solution for this?

1. IIS content expiry for the images folder after the release i can do.

Problem with this is i have to turn this on for some days probably till 99% users have accessed the site.

2. META tags, HttpCacheability.NoCache etc won't work since these are images.
3. For JS and CSS or a favicon, it is easy to add a version at the end of a link programmatically. But for images what to do? Links can come from a CSS also.

So only options i can think of are change the image names each time :(

Or add a string with all image links in the site which should be replaced (with a script) with a release version number while checking in.

is there any other options for this?

Answer (score 0):

**1- headers**

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

But sometimes, browsers ignores them.

**2- url parameters**

```
<img src="myimage.jpg?1243"/>
```

You can do this via javascript on the html or scripting server-side.

**3- .htaccess**

Programmatically add a serial to filenames in your sources:

```
 filename[.serial].ext
```

then add a .htaccess on your server than trims that serial

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesions 1. Meta tags >> It can be added in page only, it wont affect images. 2. In jquery if i try, already old image will be loaded and changing it after loading will not be proper.2 times loading and flickering might occur!! 3. I am checking the third solution

Comment: 1- Meta tags >>> these are "Cache policy header controls" and are affecting the way a browser handles the GLOBAL page cache, including ressources!  But some browser for whatever reason treat them as indicatives, not directives
2- It works, doing it all time.  
3- Heavy work, but effective.